# Why does nerd-dictation not work in LibreOffice Writer with Ubuntu 21.10?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

When I upgrade to Ubuntu 21.10 suddenly nerd-dictation stops working for some windows, particularly LibreOffice Writer. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

Because nerd-dictation requires xdotool, which in turn requires X. Ubuntu 21.10 has Wayland by default. With native Wayland applications like LibreOffice, xdotool cannot simulate keystrokes. There are possible workarounds but as of Jan 2022 the dev hasn't implemented any of them. See [nerd-dictation issue #37](https://github.com/ideasman42/nerd-dictation/issues/37) and [Document Foundation issue #146889](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=146889).

Comment: (I spent a while trying to figure out what was wrong, wanted to document the Q&A I wished had existed to hopefully save someone else some time!)